# Why angular 4 http.get buffertime operator doesnt work?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using Angular 4.4.2.

I try to make a request using http.get and buffer the emitted response until defined time. But it doesnt work whereas when I try with delay it works.

Can you explain me why ?

```
this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2')
  .bufferTime(4000)
  .subscribe(
    _ => console.log('BufferTime', _)
  );
```

Here is a Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/60vuLXBxwrj1TAAXsNtY

Thanks

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I think that instead of `bufferTime` you're looking for `delay`(?). Otherwise give more details ;)

Comment: I'm looking for BufferTime. The fact is that it is not executed. Look at the Plunkr console. 'BufferTime' is logged immediatly after the request is resolved. It should have wait for at least 4 seconds before to be logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bufferTime` emits immediately when the source observable completes.

This makes sense given the hot context it is normally expected to run in but does not work in your case.  One clumsy solution could be something like: http://plnkr.co/edit/70v61AAxZuUOCjRjFJ5n?p=preview